# Shimano 105 10 and 11 speed compatibility

Tags: shimano, cassette

Currently I have on my bike the Shimano 105 system (2 years old) with 10 speed cassette. Currently I am buying a new wheelset (Fulcrum Racing zero) made for Shimano 11 cassette. I was told that I can use my 10 speed cassette but I was planing to upgrade to 11 speed cassette in the future. Is the Shimano 11 speed cassette that comes with the latest Shimano 105 compatible with older 105 systems?

I apologize in advance if I don't make myself too clear.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you prepared to spend around $230 for a new set of 11-speed shift levers ?  Otherwise, 10-speed shifters don't work with an 11-speed casette.

Comment: I initially thought that was the answer, but it's actually a little worse than that in this case!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to go from Shimano 10 speed road to 11 speed road, you'll need a new cassette, new shifters, a new chain and a [new rear derailleur](http://velonews.competitor.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-10-11-speed-drivetrain-component-compatibility_362722), since the cable pull ratios have changed (again). Zinn also notes that 10 speed FD might not shift as nicely as 10 speed FD with the 11 speed shifters, so may as well throw one of those in.

So, in the drive train, essentially all you'd be wanting to keep is the crank if you want to go from Shimano 10 speed road to Shimano 11 speed road.

Comment: Also, you'll probably be able to buy the entire group set for less than everything minus the cranks, so you might as well upgrade the entire thing at once.  Especially when you consider that it will be much easier to sell your old groupset as a complete set.

Comment: Unless the frame is very expensive it would probably be more cost effective to buy a new bike.

Comment: Thank you very much, so if i understood correctly i can put on my 10 speed cassette with a spacer and use it with the new wheelset (that's what i've been told)

Comment: Yep - 10 speed Shimano-type cassette on 11 speed Shimano compatible freehub needs a spacer (or possibly two).

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm using 5700 rear with 6800 cassette and shifters with success. You have to adjust the stops and it works. I also run a microshift cents 10 spd rear mech with 6800. The geometry of the derailleurs is sufficient with stop adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer was easier than all you got there.
yes all is easy and compatible. All you needed was a spacer (normally provided) to be placed before the cassette on the hub, to make up for the space remaining.
But I see that you have been using it successfully already!