# Can I run a 10 speed cassette on an 11 speed wheel, but also keep running 10 speed on a 10 speed wheel?

Tags: shimano, cyclocross

I bought a second hand cyclocross bike (running Shimano 105) and I ... love it. I've been doing some short commuting on it as well, but the nobbled tires are copping a pounding.

I've got a spare set of 11 speed wheels kicking around home that came with my road bike that I upgraded. My question is, I want to put some wide road tires on the 11 speed wheels and keep the CX tires on the 10 speed wheels and just swap the wheels in and out depending on what I feel like doing.

Obviously I'd prefer not to have to tune the gears every time that I swap the wheels.

I haven't tried yet because I don't have a spare 10 speed cassette.

What's the best minimum fuss solution?

Comment: Is the bike using disk brakes as well?  If it is rim brakes, you may have to readjust them as well each time you swap.  Probably have to do that with disk brakes as well, but I don't know that.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30752/shimano-105-10-and-11-speed-compatibility

Comment: I think you'd be OK with disks (as long as the rotors were the same size.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't really considered the rim difference on the cantis that I have. I guess there's only one way to find out.

Comment: @dlu unless the hub spacing to the disc is exactly (you can do this with spacers sometimes) usually you have to adjust the caliper. I do this with my 2 wheelsets on my 160mm disc bike.

Comment: Assuming the bike has rim brakes, most rims are close enough that one can adjust the brake pads to work fine with both rim sets.  I have some wheels with 26mm wide rims which I swap with 19mm wide rims.  I compensate for the different rim width with the cable adjust barrel on the brake.  Just ensure the brake pads are adjusted so they NEVER touch the tires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use spacers on the 11 speed wheel to put a 10 speed cassette on.

See your hub manufacturer's page for details, but its normally a 1.8(5) mm spacer (which comes with the hub, but you can buy separately) and a 1mm spacer (sometimes; which you'll get with the cassette). See [this page](http://www.slowtwitch.com/Tech/Cassette_Spacers_2013_3978.html) for a table of some common cases.

Comment: @Vincent your comment should be an answer as it actually answers the question fully. Unlike the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a Shimano Ultegra 6800 wheelset (11 speed) to put on a 10 speed 105 5700 bike. The wheel came with a 1.85mm spacer. However you need to slightly adjust the derailleur and the rim brakes.

Comment: If the rim brakes need adjusting that's a sign the dish of one or both wheels is off. Just bring both rear wheels and they can do a quick check. BTW it's not uncommon for the dish to be off by a mm or two so both could be off a couple mm in opposite directions (one left, the other right) - this would be fine but will show up on the caliper brakes.

Answer (score 0):

I still live in a 6-speed world, but…

I think it would work. Do you have the tools to take the 10-speed cassette off and try it on the 11-speed wheel? The easiest thing might be just to try it. The place where you may run into problems swapping the wheels is with the placement of the cassette. If both cassettes are in the same location (the small and large cogs are in the same position relative to the centerline of the bike) then both should line up in the same way with the derailer and things should be good.

In theory it seems possible that with different hubs you might end up with the cassettes in slightly different locations and the shifting wouldn't be spot on. If that happens you could (in theory) fix it by adding spacers of the right thickness to adjust the position of one of the cassettes. This might be a bit dicey if the 10-speed is the one that needs to move, but I don't think it would be.

You will need a spacer behind the cassette (on the side towards the spokes).

Comment: The 11-speed hub will take the 10 speed cassette with said 1.85mm spacer. All  Shimano hubs (105 and up) after 2013 are 11-speed